# Celerybeat schedule executing task multiple times?

Tags: python, django, database, celery, celerybeat

I have a task *calculate_common_locations* which runs once via `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE`.
The task simply calls a function in the database:

```
@app.task
def calculate_common_locations():
    db.execute("SELECT * FROM calculate_centroids('b')")
```

This is the entry in `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE`:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
   'common_locations': {
        'task': 'clients.tasks.calculate_common_locations',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=23, day_of_week='sun'), #every week
    },
    [..]
}
```

The schedule includes more tasks that run *once a day* or *every 10 seconds*. These tasks seem to be not re-run many times.
Celery flower shows the task is executed more than 20 times.
The first one started as scheduled, runs ~100s, succeeds and then starts again.

[image]

There is only one celerybeat running:

```
ps -Af | grep celerybeat 
foo     24359   779  0 01:53 ?        00:00:04 [celeryd: celery@celery:MainProcess] -active- (worker --beat --app=cloud.celeryapp:app --concurrency=10 -l INFO -s /home/foo/run/celerybeat-schedule --pidfile=/home/foo/run/celerybeat.pid)
```

This is how celery gets started (via supervisord):

```
celery worker --beat --app=cloud.celery app:app --concurrency=10 -l INFO -s /home/foo/run/celerybeat-schedule --pidfile=/home/foo/run/celerybeat.pid
```

I have tested it without the *--concurrency=10* switch. The database function is still executed multiple times.

The function reads from a large table (> 1 Mil rows) that is inserted into quite often (a couple of times a second). Postgres locks show that all locks are granted.

Is it possible that the task is being re-run because the query terminates at some point?

**There is no issues when:**

- the task is run from the django shell (directly or via `.delay()`),
- the task's content is replaced by a lightweight sql query (select * from test),
- the task's content is replaced by a *sleep(100)*.

Versions:

- **celery==3.1.12**
- **psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may make more sense if you consider what `crontab(hour=23, day_of_week='sun')` does:

```
>>> crontab(hour=23, day_of_week='sun')
<crontab: * 23 sun * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>
```

So what this means is that the task will execute **every minute** at 11pm every sunday.

If you want it to execute only at the first minute you can specify:

```
crontab(minute=0, hour=23, day_of_week='sun')
```

Comment: Stupid me, thanks for that enlightenment. I have added minute=0 and the task runs once.